# Latitude & Longitude issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, google-maps-api-3

I want Zipcode list by given Zipcode and radius.

E.g - If I enter Zipcode for e.g `'111111'` and set Miles `'50'` it may return list of  Pin Code between the radius.

If List of Zipcode we can't get then try to get all latitude and longitude of given radius.

Comment: Are you expecting sql server to just understand zip codes, or do you have a database of zipcodes and their associated lat/long?

Comment: yes sir i Want to exactly same things https://www.freemaptools.com/find-zip-codes-inside-radius.htm like that but google api

Comment: That is no doubt based on a big database of zipcodes, with their lat/long. Do you have that data?

Comment: no sir i haven't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes I found a WebService that does exactly what i need. You could provide only a simple ZipCode and a country or perhaps a full address and in the response you get the longitude/latitude. Then i send the Latitude and Longitude returned to get a list of all the ZipCodes near the provided coordinates and a given Radius that also can be customized. You can filter the total rows you want the service to return, or even if you are gonna use miles or kilometers as the measure unit.

So, basically with the returned information, i feed those coordinates for each of the nearest ZipCodes obtained to the google API and render those points of interest into the map that you need to show.

The services are provided by GeoNames. Its an organization dedicated to Geolocalization services. They offer also premium data, but in particular these services are free of use, obviously the information is not as accurate as the premium one, but actually in my tests i found that that is trustful and the response also is very fast. Another good advantage is that the process to get a Key for use Geonames services it's quite simple.

I left you the link of the services that i'm talking about.

List of available services: http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html

Hope it helps many people. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Based on you amazing description of your question, it seems that you have a geospatial problem.

A) you will need a geospatial datastore with postcodes as points or perhaps a polygon .
b) now you are after a prefix search which is a simple sql query with a geodistance filter.

You could easily do this with something like elasticsearch or Postgis or even spatiallite.

There are other ways as well, but geodistance is the easiest way to get this, look at this example which uses [elasticsearch](https://github.com/varunpant/AroundMe)